# Not found exception while doing svn update

Tags: java, svn, atomic

I'm having the following situation:

- A configuration file (config.cfg) that gets accessed a lot by
  different processes.
- Config.cfg is under version control - SVN.

I develop and test on a staging environment, when everything is working I go to the server and execute `svn up` on the config.cfg.

The problem is: During `svn up` I get an exception by the processes accessing config.cfg: **"config.cfg" not found**.

It seems that svn causes a short period where the file is beeing replaced and therefore not accessible for my processes.

Any input on how to solve this issue is very much appreciated.

Comment: Updating a file while processes are actively reading from it seems...not wise. I would consider some kind of [file locking mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) to avoid this.

Comment: I don't see how I can apply this concept in my case. I'm running "svn up" in the shell when I'm rolling out new configuration files. So there is nothing I can do programmatically.

Comment: "there is nothing I can do" is a pretty broad statement. You might want to investigate more before coming to a conclusion like that. If you control the code to the processes accessing the config file(s), you can add a bit to access a semaphore file; then you can wrap `svn up` in a script that checks the same semaphore file to see if it's safe to update the file. There are many different permutations you could consider.

Comment: True :-) Shame on me.
I will implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by ThisSuitIsBlackNot the way to go is to use a semaphor file.

Another solution which just came to my mind is to cache the config file in the process. If it is not there the cached version of the config file is used. As "svn update" doesn't take very long the process will work with cached version until it needs to use the config file the next time.